# Shadow under UIActivityIndicator on iPhone/iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiactivityindicatorview

I want to create shadow under animated UIActivityIndicator to display that other ui elements are inactive, like shadow under keyboard or alert-view. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a view with a black background and opacity to 50% with something like this :

```
UIView *shadowView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame];
[shadowView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[shadowView setOpacity:0.5];

[yourCurrentView addSubview:shadowView];
[yourCurrentView bringSubviewToFront:yourActivityIndicator];
```

Comment: You could make a PNG with transparency going from almost opaque to almost transparent in the middle and set this as a view under your activity indicator if you want it to look like the alert view one